# How to notify errors to atom using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, atom-editor

Hi I'm trying to run a "build system" for babel using atom editor and gulp. 
I use gulp as build js system. Now there's a lot of atom plugins out there which run gulp script from atom... but I'd like to notify compiler error to gulp

example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('js/main.js')
    .pipe(browserify({ debug: true }))
    .on('error', onError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts'], function() {
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
});

function onError(err) {
  console.log(err);
  //***************HERE I WOULD LIKE SOMETHING LIKE
  //notify-to-atom(err.pos,err.message);
  this.emit('end');
}
```

so I'd like to get something like notify-to-atom and I expect to bring from atom to position and see error message.

Some like eslinter plugin for atom

thanks